# Visual Studio 2012 crashing when called web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I added a SOAP web service as "web reference" in visual studio. I am working on an MVC application. I have it working fine in a console application but not in MVC. I can call the methods but when I try to create an instance of the web service, a huge memory leak happens and Visual Studio crashes. The Reference.cs file contains about 300k lines, which I am commenting out everything that I am not using. I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

2 hours later + 250k lines commented out = PROBLEM SOLVED!!

Comment: I commented out most of the auto generated Reference.cs. I only left the code that I am using!